# Algorithm to find the determinant of a matrix

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, determinants

I have to write an algorithm to find the determinant of a matrix, which is done with the recursive function:

[image]

where `A_ij` is the matrix, which appears when you remove the `i`th row and the `j`th column for `A`. When `A` has dimension `n x n`, then the dimension for `A_ij` is `(n-1) x (n-1)`. I'm not allowed to use `Minor[]` or `Det[]`.

How do I write this algorithm?

---

This is the code I have so far:

```
det1[Mi_ /; Dimensions[Mi][[1]] == Dimensions[Mi][[2]]] :=
  Module[{det1}, 
    det1 = Sum[ 
      If[det1 == 1, Break[], (-1)^(1 + j) *Mi[[1, j]]*det1[Drop[Mi, {1}, {j}]]], 
      {j, 1, Length[Mi]}]; 
    Return[det1 // MatrixForm, Module]
]
```

Comment: Is this homework by any chance?

Comment: What do you have so far?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot..
Here is my code, until now, but doesn't work:


det1[Mi_ /; Dimensions[Mi][[1]] == Dimensions[Mi][[2]]] := 
 Module[{det1},
  det1 = Sum[
    If[det1 == 1, 
     Break[], (-1)^(1 + j) *Mi[[1, j]]*det1[Drop[Mi, {1}, {j}]]], {j, 
     1, Length[Mi]}]; Return[det1 // MatrixForm, Module]]

Comment: @user1098185 Please add the code to the main question.  You can use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8507654/edit) link.

Comment: det1[Mi_ /; Dimensions[Mi][[1]] == Dimensions[Mi][[2]]] := 
 Module[{det1},
  det1 = Sum[
    If[det1 == 1, 
     Break[], (-1)^(1 + j) *Mi[[1, j]]*det1[Drop[Mi, {1}, {j}]]], {j, 
     1, Length[Mi]}]; Return[det1 // MatrixForm, Module]]

Comment: I'd start by using a local variable that isn't the same as the name of your function and by making sure you have a base case for the recursion.  Also, the `MatrixForm` isn't needed, since the result is a scalar, not a matrix.

Comment: What do you mean by Base case?

Comment: By "base case" I mean the same as item #2 in Szabolcs answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why doesn't your code work?

1. `MatrixForm` is used for formatting (display), but a MatrixForm-wrapped matrix can't be used in calculations.  You simply need to remove it.
2. Think about your stopping condition for the recursion: the determinant of a 1*1 matrix is just the single element of the matrix.  Rewrite the sum and `If` based on this.  If the matrix is of size 1, return its element (it's impossible to `Break[]` out of a recursion).
3. Don't use a local variable with the same name as your function: this masks the global function and makes it impossible to call recursively.
4. Finally, this doesn't *break* the function, but an explicit `Return` is not necessary.  The last value of a [`CompoundExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompoundExpression.html) is simply returned.

---

To summarize, `det[m_] := If[Length[m] == 1, m[[1,1]], (Laplace expansion here)]`.  An alternative is to use pattern matching to identify size-1 matrices:

```
Clear[det]
det[{{x_}}] := x
det[m_] := (Laplace expansion)
```

Comment: How does Laplace's formula involve in this? im confused, sorry

Comment: I mean the same formula you posted: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve your problem?

```
Clear[det];
det[{{x_}}] := x;
det[a_ /; MatrixQ[a] && SameQ @@ Dimensions[a]] := 
 Sum[(-1)^(1 + i) a[[1, i]] det[Drop[a, {1}, {i}]], {i, 1, Length[a]}];
det::gofish = "Unable to handle this type of input: ``";
det[a___] := (Message[det::gofish, HoldForm[det][a]]; $Failed)
```

E.g., this:

```
In[]:=

m = {{a, b, c}, {c, d, e}, {f, g, h}};
Det[m] === Expand[det[m]]
```

gives:

```
Out[]= 

True
```